# Handlebar js - Second array in JSON object wont print onto table

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the following:

**handlebardemo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Handlebar demo - user table</title>
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/handlebars-v4.0.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebar2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="usertable" class="w3-table-all">
        <script id="user-table-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Real Name</th>  
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Group</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#users}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{username}}</td>
                            <td>{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</td>
                            <td>{{email}}</td>
                            <td>{{group.groupname}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {{/users}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**handlebar2.js**

```
$(function(){
    var source = $("#user-table-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var data = { users: [
          {username: "Alan87", firstname: "Alan", lastname:"Johnson", email:"alan@test.com"},
          {username: "JeffABC", firstname: "Jeff", lastname:"Beck", email:"jeff@test.com"},
          {username: "Sarah_R_1990", firstname: "Sarah", lastname:"Reilly", email:"sarah@test.com"}
          ], group: [
          {groupname:"Dev"},
          {groupname:"QA"},
          {groupname:"Dir"},
       ]}
    $("#usertable").append(template(data));
});
```

The first array in data, users, prints out fine into the table, but i cant seem to get the values in groups to print onto a 4th column. I don't have the best grasp on the Handlebars  syntax etc., yet so I may be missing something obvious here. I tried `<td>{{../group.groupname}}</td>` but that didn't seem to do anything, and the approach outlined in the files above hasn't worked out either. I also tried `<td>{{../group}}</td>` but this printed out [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] in the last column for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
  <td>
    {{#each ../group}}
     {{groupname}}
    {{/each}}
  </td>
```

Comment: I tried that, the last column is then blank. Sorry, this was a typo, I had groups.groupname rather than your suggestion. Line in question has been edited

Comment: Yes, that's because you have an array, you need to iterate over them, I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Now I'm getting somewhere. It now prints out Dev QA and Dir in the last column on each row presumably because its iterating over the entire group array rather than taking the current index and using that, I need it to print one per row, e.g. alan87 dev, jeffabc qa and so on

Comment: Just put the `#each` inside the `<td>`. (answer updated)

Comment: Or actually to print one per row — you need to change the source data, you need to move the corresponding `groupname` into the same object which contains the `username`. It should be done before rendering the handlebars template.

Comment: ah, so its not possible to do it the way I originally started?

Comment: Yep, you  can not do it with handlebars unless you write some tricky helpers using `@index` variable. It will be much simpler and cleaner to just preprocess the data, so it look like `{username: "Alan87", group: "Dev", ...}`